# Can't generate leaders with EasyCustomLabeling

Tags: qgis

I'm using EasyCustomLabeling with QGIS 2.0.1 and can't get it to generate the leader lines it is supposed to in Action 2.  I create a new layer with EasyCustomLabeling, move labels to new locations, and then save the layer.  I'm not sure how to get it to generate the lines to connect the points and labels after this however.

Any help would be much apprecaited

Answer (score 1):

You must to select your labels' layer, then press `Toggle Editing`. If you'll select the labels you'll see the lines, like below:

[image]

If then you choose the move tool, and you try to move the selection you'll see red lines:

[image]